# node js path.join(directory + '\\' + file) in mac not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, directory, cross-platform

I am not able to fetch the directory using node js path.join(directory + '\' + file) and hence its giving me error "No such file or directory found".
But In windows platform its working fine.
Can anyone suggest what should I use for Mac/Linux OS for reading the directory?

Comment: I see no actual code, so just a guess, Linux use forward slash, not backslash, but typically you should be fine with `path.join('dir','file')`

Answer (score 2):

You only have to provide the path parts to the Node's `path.join` method as below, and it will join them using **the platform-specific separator** as a delimiter.

```
path.join(directory, file)
```

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

or you can provide the path separator also to the above method using [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep) constant as follows.

```
path.join(directory, path.sep, file)
```

Comment: if i don't provide separator it directly appending string without any seprator

Comment: That's strange. Then please try `path.join(directory, path.sep, file)`